# Where are the /dev folder and the /dev/null device located on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

I am trying to find them on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion and it seems they do not exist. 
I do not think it is a problem of folders privileges.

Maybe it just doesn't exit and I have to create them.

Answer (score 8):

It should be there as a character special file:

```
bash-3.2# cd /dev
bash-3.2# ls -l |grep null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel       3,   2 Mar  8 11:04 null
```

Finder doesn't show these folders so you need to be in terminal to see them.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick answer. I didn't see them in Finder (while I can see hidden files) but did in iTerm.

Comment: And `ls -leO / | grep dev` shows that it's hidden which you already knew. I wouldn't be surprised if Finder had a special case black list of places to not show, even when hidden files are presented.